# Displaying a remote window in a EOD session

Tags: x11, display, remote-desktop

Please can someone tell me how to display a remote window in a EOD session?

The usual way of setting "setenv DISPLAY local.host.com:192" in the remote session and doing a "xhost +" in the remote session doesn't seem to work.

The local host information obtained using "echo $HOST" in the EOD session doesn't seem to work in setting DISPLAY.

Comment: `xhost` is dangerous. Any one on you network could seriously damage the data on your computer.

Comment: Can you tell us, what is EOD?

Comment: EOD - Exceed On Demand.

Comment: If you do use `xhost` (I am not recommending this, when logged in to an account that you care about), then you have to do `xhost` on the local machine (the one with the X-server).

Comment: Show us what you have done. include tested code, and output.